# How to use localized date formats I've defined?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am translating a site to French. I am using [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation), and several other modules.

By default, at `admin/config/regional/date-time`, there are a bunch of date types already defined with formats selected for the default language.

- I used `hook_date_formats()` and defined a set of analogous formats for French, and they do correctly appear at `admin/config/regional/date-time/locale/fr/edit`.
- I set my user language to French and also changed the default country to France at `admin/config/regional/settings`.

**My dates, in Views and in other spots, are still not translated.** The only way to make them work is to manually choose the formats I want at `admin/config/regional/date-time`, but that changes them independently of my language and country. Am I missing something getting this to work?